# How to convert strings to abbreviations

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, text-processing

I want to do something like this if i have a textual transcript of a speech recognition system i want to convert this text like this - Triple A converts in AAA. Can someone help ?

Comment: Could just do a simple find and replace: s/Triple A/AAA/g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Repeating 3 times

If what you mean is that the string "Triple" is to be treated as a keyword whose following string's value is to be replaced by itself tripled, then the following can accomplish what you want:

```
def tripler(s):
    triples = 0
    s = [ss.strip() for ss in s.split()][::-1]

    for i in range(len(s) - 1):
        if s[i - triples + 1] == 'Triple':
            s[i - triples] *= 3

            del s[i - triples + 1]
            triples += 1

    return ' '.join(s[::-1])
```

### Dynamic repetitions

To repeat the argument any number of times, a dictionary with different keywords and corresponding values could be used:

```
repeat_keywords = {'Double':2, 'Triple':3}

def repeater(s):
    repeats = 0
    s = [ss.strip() for ss in s.split()][::-1]

    for i in range(len(s) - 1):
        if s[i - repeats + 1] in repeat_keywords:
            s[i - repeats] *= repeat_keywords[s[i - repeats + 1]]

            del s[i - repeats + 1]
            repeats += 1

    return ' '.join(s[::-1])
```

**Inputs**:
1. Double x Triple y
2. Double Triple y
3. Triple x Double Double y Triple z Double

**Outputs**:
1. xx yyy
2. yyyyyy
3. xxx yyyy zzz Double

**Note**: this solution also has the effect of multiplying the value of repeated keywords. That is due to parsing the string in reverse.

Comment: Yes i do exactly this but what about five a , two a and so on?

Comment: Means i have to create individual functions for all possible cases ?

Comment: I edited my answer to include dynamic repetition numbers.

Comment: It outputes same string that i was given in input tripler("Triple A") outputs "Triple A"

Comment: @EshanAgarwal Judging from the comments and post, it's the solution to your question. Take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and consider accepting / upvoting the answer.